# LINUX Bash - Recursively Create Intermediary Directories and Move Files of Type Into New Directories

Tags: linux, bash

I've used StackExchange before and lurked on SuperUser but first time posting. Here's what I'm trying to do. (Pseudo)

```
For Each DIR containing $file *.Item
    Mkdir ./dir1/dir2
    Mv $file ./dir1/dir2/$file
```

Basically I have a folder structure full of files of type .Item, in every directory containing a file of type .Item I want to create 2 new sub directories call them dir1/dir2/ then I want to move all files of type .Item into those sub directories.

So far I've had luck doing some of the pieces of this but not all of it at once. I apologize if this has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is to avoid moving the files more than once. A naïve loops risks finding `dir/x.Item`, moving it to `dir/dir1/dir2/x.Item`, and then finding `dir/dir1/dir2/x.Item` and moving it to `dir/dir1/dir2/dir1/dir2/x.Item`, and then ...

Although I couldn't get Gnu `find` to do this in a couple of minutes of testing, I do note that Posix says "If a file is removed from or added to the directory hierarchy being searched it is unspecified whether or not `find` includes that file in its search." So one should be defensive.

So the easiest safe solution is to first construct the list of files, and then process the list.

If no `.Item` file has a newline character in its name, then it's easy to use `find` to construct the list. Assuming there are not too many files, this can be done directly into a bash array:

```
mapfile -t files < <(find . -name '*.Item')
```

Then it's straightforward to process the files:

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  # make the target directory if it doesn't yet exist (-p)
  mkdir -p "$(dirname "$f")"/dir1/dir2
  # move the file
  mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/dir1/dir2
done
```

If there are a lot of files, we need to be more efficient and less cavalier about memory. We can construct a list of directories instead of a list of files (`sort -u` eliminates duplicates):

```
mapfile -t dirs < <(find . -name '*.Item' -printf %h | sort -u)
```

Now we can process the directories:

```
for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p "$d/dir1/dir2"
  mv "$d/*.Item" "$d/dir1/dir2"
done
```

Finally, if there were a lot of directories, we could use a temporary file instead of an array:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
find . -name '*.Item' -printf %h | sort -u > "$tmp"
while IFS= read -r dir; do
  mkdir -p "$d/dir1/dir2"
  mv "$d/*.Item" "$d/dir1/dir2"
done < "$tmp"
rm "$tmp"
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Unfortunately I wasn't able to get any of the above solutions to work out of the box, mostly because the mapfile command just hung on me when I ran it. There were only 210 files so I doubt that was the issue. I am on cygwin but I did verify that I had the mapfile command available. In the end your answer gave me the idea to use `find . -iname '*.Item' > MapFile` and then simply `cat MapFile | while read f; do mkdir -p "$(dirname "$f")"/dir1/dir2 ; mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")"/dir1/dir2 ; done` but I am curious why I wasn't able to use mapfile!

Comment: @DouglasMiller: My mistake; a couple of less-thans didn't make the transition into the answer. (It should be `mapfile ... < <(...)`). Corrected the answer, and my apologies.